# Trying to start VPNC from PHP exec()

Tags: php, exec, vpn

I am trying to start my VPN connection (using VPNC) from PHP.  I have to do it this way because it is closed remotely if there isn't activity so I can't just leave it running on the server.  I am able to do it from the command line by typing:

```
/usr/local/sbin/vpnc --natt-mode force-natt
```

This works.  It doesn't require any input from me because I'm storing the password in it's conf file.  This does not work from PHP:

```
exec('/usr/local/sbin/vpnc --natt-mode force-natt', $output, $result);
echo $result.',';
print_r($output);
```

The output is:

```
1,Array
(
)
```

Safe mode is off, the "/usr/local/sbin" directory is allowed via open_basedir, and vpnc is executable by all users.  Any ideas why I can't get the VPN connection going this way?

Comment: Just a quick sanity check: is_executable('/usr/local/sbin/vpnc') ?

Comment: Also, check which user your script is being run as, and whether that user can read the conf file you were talking about.

Comment: 1) That does return true
2) I set the config files to 755 so any user should be able to read and execute them

Comment: I just tried logging in as a non root user and I'm getting errors.  So I'm thinking my problem is permissions based.  Here is the errors:

/usr/local/sbin/vpnc: Error binding to source port. Try '--local-port 0'
Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0:500: Permission denied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out the problem was needing to call it using "sudo."  VPNC has to be called from root.  I've posted more info here: http://bkwld.com/blog/2009/10/vpn-through-php-on-mt/